# Protection level of method to use with generics

Tags: c#, generics, protected

My generic class is defined as follows:

```
public class MySortedList<TKey, TItem> where TItem : MyClass<TKey>
```

In one of class' methods I create an instance of TItem and call one of its protected methods:

```
TItemInstance.MyMethod();
```

Here I get the error that

> MyMethod is inaccessible due to its protection level

What level of protection should MyMethod have?
Thank You.

Comment: the class in which you have `MyMethod` function must be `public`.

Comment: It should be `public` or `internal`, since it's used from outside `TItem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods declared as `protected` can only be used in the classes and their subclasses.

If you want to use method outside of the class, you should declare it as `public`:

```
public void MyMethod()
```

or, if the caller is defined in the same assembly, `internal`:

```
internal void MyMethod()
```

Comment: Same assembly = same namespace?

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg, not exactly. Assembly is library, either `exe` or `dll` file. Most likely in your case this is a project you are working with. Namespace however is a logical way or organization of your types. One namespace can be declared in several assemblies. Here is [a good post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx#assenamesp_topic5) that describes these concepts in depth.

Answer (score 1):

Because `MySortedList` isn't derived from `TItem` then you will need to make the method in question public for it to be callable from `MySortedList`.

You can only call protected methods from the defining class or one of its derived classes.

See [the Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The class in which you have `MyMethod` function must be declare as `public` because here you want to use that method outside the class. So it should be `public`.